# TextInput start from right to left, React native

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a TextInput like in the image, when the text too long, it starts from right to left although I added CSS textAlign: 'left' but it does not work. It happens just on android, on ios it's good. Anybody got the same problem before?[image]

My code:

```
<View style={styles.myInput}>
                <TextInput numberOfLines={1} style={styles.input} placeholder="Tìm kiếm địa chỉ..." value={search} placeholderTextColor='gray' onChangeText={value => setSearch(value)} />
                <Ionicons style={styles.inputIcon} name="md-search" color='gray' size={20}
                    onPress={onSearch}
                ></Ionicons>
            </View>
 myInput: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 45,
    top: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    width: '90%',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 5,
    position: 'relative',
    marginHorizontal: '5%',
    zIndex: 1
},
input: {
    height: 40,
    color: '#000',
    height: '100%',
    paddingRight: 30
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use prop: selection({start: 0}) when inputText onblur

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  It only happened with some Android devices. I put this in my App.js file and it fixed it.

```
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";

I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```